# Heroku properties file

Tags: java, heroku, properties-file

I am using a properties file to hardcode a list of valid usernames in a Java webapp.

The file is placed in the same package as the class (which is a struts action) and is read as follows:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;
input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("login.properties");
prop.load(input);
String[] aprovedUsers = prop.getProperty("approvedUsers").split(",");
```

It works ok when I test it locally (in an Apache server running as localhost), but when I deploy the webapp to heroku, it seems that it can't read the propoerties file as `input` is `null`.

Is there a special consideration that needs to be taken into account when using properties files in heroku?

EDIT: My Procfile is

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

I am using Jetty as container.

Comment: can you share your `Procfile`?

Comment: I have added the `Procfile` as edition to the question

Comment: Are you running it locally with `heroku local`? Can you reproduce the error that way?

Answer (score 0):

Your `local classpath` and `heroku classpath` are different. Refer to `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` in order to find file.

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("login.properties").getPath());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that it don't work locally (on Apache as localhost). The error is `SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @JoseOspina, could you please share the path where is `login.properties`? Is it in `java/resources`? Is it in `WEB-INF`? Could you check *.war, does it contain `login.properties` somewhere?

Comment: The file is copied, after built by eclipse, in `\target\classes\coproject\cpweb\actions\json`. Before it is built, it is in `src\main\java\coproject\cpweb\actions\json`

Comment: Try please `InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("coproject/cpweb/actions/json /login.properties")`

Comment: With your last suggestion, still `null`. I have modified the previous one to `URL resource = getClass().getResource("login.properties"); String loginPath = resource.getPath(); input = new FileInputStream(loginPath);` and it worked locally, but not in heroku. I had to change `getSystemResource` for `getResource`

Comment: the `loginPath` returned is `app folder/coprojects-hk/target/classes/coproject/cpweb/actions/json/login.properties`